# is there any way to load csv file in aws opensearch?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, opensearch

hi anyone knows how to upload csv file to aws opensearch directly using api call (like bulk api of aws).I want to do this using nodejs, i don't want to use kinesis or logstash also make sure that upload must be happen in chunks .I tried a lot but couldn't make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

Opensearch provide [javascript](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/clients/javascript/) client. You can use [Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/bulk_examples.html) to upload documents in chunks.

**Update 1:**

As you mentioned you want yo index directly CSV file then use [elasticsearch-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch-csv) NPM package.

Comment: I know I can use bulk api but for that data must be in json format here I don't want to read CSV file because size of file is too large and reading records from it is very expensive I just want to know a way where I just have to mention a file name and it gets uploaded

Comment: As i know you need to convert it to JSON only and then upload it. last option i can see is Logstash but as you mentioned already you dont want to use logstash as well.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: Ok thanks Sagar for your response can you tell me what is the way to to upload json

Comment: And can i upload json file as chunks

Comment: Did you try the NPM package i have mentioned in answer? If you want to go with JSON then first convert your csv to json and pass json chunk by chunk to bulk api.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242548/discussion-between-yash-mathur-and-sagar-patel).